# Expanding the regression line and standard error on GGPLOT?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, scatter-plot

I've bumped into some trouble with one of my scatterplots on ggplot in RStudio - I expanded the x-axis limits to be uniform with other graphs I have, but it now the SE and regression line do not span the full graph.

```
ggplot(LATINX, aes(x = CULTAX, y = PSS)) +
geom_point(color = "#8E3B46") + 
geom_smooth(method="lm", se = TRUE, color = "#D63230") + 
theme_apa() +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(7, 35), breaks = c(10, 20, 30)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(15, 120), breaks = c(30, 60, 90, 120))
```

[image]

If anyone has any idea on how to fix this, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fullrange` argument in `geom_smooth()` to extrapolate from predictors that *can* extrapolate. (For example `method = "loess"` cannot).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fullrange = TRUE) +
  # Make x-axis wider than data
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), expand = c(0,0))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much oh my goodness!!! That's exactly what I needed!